# Database Table design Help

Tags: database-design

I just want to understand and avoid mistakes ..
I have this input table , so I designed this database to manage it , 
my question is : Is the design of StudentMarks good or bad in Normalization ?
I need help please .
[image: The input form paper]

[image: My database design]

Answer (score 2):

It's not normalized. `StudentMarks` has one value for `homework.` That does not sound ideal.

Makes more sense, to me, to have a another table GRADES, or the like. `CREATE TABLE grades ( category text, grade float )`. Then you can insert into it `VALUES ('homework', 100)` keep all those grades and then later at query time `avg()` them.